# How to get stadistics of the traffic of every device connected via my Android phone hotspot

Tags: android, traffic, hotspot

`TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid)` gets the traffic of an app. But, I do not know which UID is the WiFi hotspot (which is a system app).

`AID_WIFI`'s UID is `1010`, so I have tried `TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(1010)` when the WiFi hotspot is opened and another phone connect is connected to it (and searching retrieving some pictures from the Internet), but it just return `-1`.

If I run:

```
int uid = 1010;
long rx = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid);
sb.append("接受mobile：" + rx);
long tx = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
sb.append("发送mobile：" + rx);
long rx1 =  TrafficStats.getUidRxPackets(uid);
sb.append("接受wifi：" + rx1);
long tx1 = TrafficStats.getUidTxPackets(uid);
sb.append("发送wifi：" + tx1);
Log.e("test111",sb.toString());
```

The console log output is:

```
接受mobile：-1
发送mobile：-1
接受wifi：-1
发送wifi：-1
```